# How to fill field in a table with a value from a dropdown list in different form using php

Tags: php, html, database

I'm not very good at php and databases so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have a drop down list in a form, I also have a column table (in a different form) that I need to populate with the value that is selected from the dropdown list via a get method to the table when a submit button is pressed.

Could someone please assist me with this?

Comment: Can't you simply do this using js? and can we see the relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$link=mysqli_connect("$host","$user","$pass");
mysqli_select_db("$db_name");
$sql_query="SELECT * FROM table WHERE droplist='example' ORDER BY name ASC";
$result=mysqli_query($sql_query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $droplist_names[]=$row['name'];
    $droplist_url[]=$row['url'];
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>

<form>
<select class="select" onChange="if(this.selectedIndex!=0) self.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">

<?php
for($i=0; $i<count($droplist_names); ++$i){
   echo "<option value='$droplist_url[$i]'>$droplist_names[$i]</option>";
}
?>

</select>
</form>
```

Comment: My example is using a mysql table that has a column named "droplist", "name", and "url".  Each entry in the mysql table would have to have  "example" in the droplist column for it to show up in the select list, the url and name would be unique to each option.